# Windows Azure specific version?

Tags: windows, mongodb, azure, memcached

Why is there a specific version of [`MongoDb`](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/windows-azure/) for windows azure? The normal windows version seems to work just fine? What's the difference between those two?

This seems to be the case for a lot of applications, including [`memcached`](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/memcached-in-windows-azure) which someone have made a windows azure port of.

Why would I use a windows azure version of any application? What do I gain?

Comment: I do not see any place in the documentation you mentioned any version details requirement for MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is there a specific version of MongoDb for windows azure? The normal windows version seems to work just fine? What's the difference between those two?

The normal [MongoDB install](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) requires an existing Windows environment.

The [MongoDB Installer for Windows on Azure](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows-azure/) includes the provisioning of Azure VMs as well as installation of MongoDB.  Provisioning options can also include selecting an Azure data centre location and creating multiple VMs for a replica set.

There is also a package to deploy [MongoDB Worker Roles](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/deploy-mongodb-worker-roles-in-azure/) using Azure's Platform-as-a-Service instances.

> Why would I use a windows azure version of any application? What do I gain?

If you use the normal Windows installer, you have to create the Azure instances yourself and then download & install MongoDB.  If you are creating a replica set you will have to repeat this for each node and add the configuration manually.

The Azure installer simplifies the number of manual steps needed to get your deployment up and running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Stennie :) - As I get it, those installers for `Windows Azure` just includes some extra options about how to install/run the application? - Does this mean, that if I run ex. both mongodb and an app on the same Azure VM, I could just as well go with the standard MongoDB Windows installer?

Comment: @ebb: If you want to use the standard MongoDB Windows installer in an existing Azure VM, that's fine (and a normal installation approach). There is no difference in the actual MongoDB executable files.

Comment: The Azure installer looks like it should help if it wasn't bug-ridden and practically useless.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Have you reported any of your issues with the installer in the MongoDB [AZURE project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/AZURE)?

Comment: I haven't because the issues I encounted have been reported for more than 6 months without resolution or even response from the team. Almost seems as though the project is dead.

Comment: @M.Babcock: Project is definitely not dead. I don't see any issues related to the installer .. do you perhaps mean the worker roles instead? Appreciate if you could point me at a few specific issues :)

Comment: Example: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/-0mubwJzhzc/VFGj6pVgvUsJ